# Set Background Color of Page if Parameter in URL

Tags: html, jsp, background-color

This is my first time using JSP and I a little stuck on the logic of how to actually do this problem. The problem is to set the background color of the webpage according to what the user enters into the parameter of the URL, if there is no parameter value then set the webpage to white. If the parameter is "random" then generate a random color. However if the parameter is red, set the background color to red. If the parameter is green, set the background color to green and so forth.

I am a little stuck on the logic of this, of how to actually store a variable with what the value of the parameter is and also the logic of how to apply the background color the user has entered in the parameter.

Here is the code: (I am using NetBeans to code this - not sure if that is of any helpful information)

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : 28-Jan-2014, 10:39:07 PM
    Author     : Owner
--%>

<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
            ul
            {
                list-style-type: none;
            }            
        </style>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>JSP Test</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Current Time: <%= new java.util.Date() %> </li>
            <li>Server Name: <%= application.getServerInfo() %> </li>
            <li>Session ID: <%= session.getId()%></li>
        </ul>

        <!--Read in request parameter in url and set background color accordingly-->
        <%
            if(request.getParameterNames() == null){
              //set page to white
            %> 
               <body bgcolor=white> 

           <%}else{
              //set page to the color of the parameter name
              Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames()



            } %>


    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You pass the color as a parameter called color - so your url look like localhost/App/page?color=red

now in jsp you can get this value through el like this - ${param.color}

now use javascript to set the color like this -

```
var color = '${param.color}';

if(color!='')

document.body.style.background = 'white';

else if(color=='random')

document.body.style.background = randomColor();//write code to generate random color

else

document.body.style.background = color;
```

Comment: you mean ${param.color} is not working. if it is so can you see any parameter named color in the url just do a cross check.